# Not working the modal window of gallery (JS files)

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a trouble with fancyBox LightBox Alternative. I do everything like in the manual, but gallery just not working.

***1. Connecting all files.***

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
     
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>

<script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  openEffect : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none'
 });
});
</script>
```

```html
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="/big_picture">
  <img src="/small_picture" width="150" height="228" alt="" />
</a>
```

***2. Nothing works. =(***

I found a bug in the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function

in line:

```js
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but... Have you downloaded the referenced css and js files? Your code has no error.

Comment: Are there are errors being reported in the console?

Comment: It won't work in the snippet because you're referencing local folders. You'll need to find [a CDN like cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fancybox) and use the URLs from that...

Comment: @LucasSouza ofcourse =)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Wow! Did not know. Everything is connected, but the site does not have a file jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js (!) Where else can find it streaming?

Comment: This file are available at: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/zipball/v2.1.5

Comment: @LucasSouza Of course. But it needs to be loaded. Where it can be downloaded from the support streaming?

Comment: Are you sure you need that file for your example? It would appear that is specifically about the mousewheel. Is that what your question is about? You really need to expand on what exactly is not working. See [ask] for tips on what makes a good question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry, just interesting.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan However, the main thing that is not working. I am added files from the Web by your advice. Also I'm has copied the entire directory of files on Apache. (with links in start-topic) Nothing helps

Comment: And again, we need to know, in the question itself (you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34294392/edit) your question), what you mean by "not working"... Are there errors in the console? Have you tried debugging at all? Again, the advice in [ask] can help you structure your question in a good way. Right now, this is very unclear.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Please see the head of the theme. I wrote in  the title that does not work and added error from the console.